# problems separating class and source files

Tags: java, directory-structure

In my `_Mathematics` package. I've separated the source files into `bin` and `src` folders like so:

```
_Mathematics ->

    Formulas ->

       src ->

           // source files containing mathematical formulas...
           // Factorial.java 

       bin ->

           // Factorial.class
           // class files containing mathematical formulas...

   Problems ->

       src ->

           // Permutation.java
           // source files containing mathematical problems...

       bin ->

           // Permutation.class
           // class files containing mathematical problems...
```

But, when I compile the file with `main()`, there is an error like so:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _Mathematics\Problems
\bin\Permutations (wrong name: _Mathematics/Problems/bin/Permutations)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Here's the `Permutation.java` file, where `main()` is located.

```
package _Mathematics.Problems.bin;
import _Mathematics.Formulas.bin.Factorial;

public class Permutations {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.printf("There are 10 students. Five are to be chosen and seated in a row for a picture.%nHow many linear arrangements are possible?%n" + 
            (new Factorial(10).r/new Factorial(5).r) + "%n%n");
        System.out.printf("How many permutations are there in the word 'permutation'?%n" + 
            new Factorial(11).r + "%n%n");
    }
}
```

And here is the other file I have, `Factorial.java`:

```
package _Mathematics.Formulas.bin;

public class Factorial {
    public int o;
    public long r;
    public Factorial(int num) {
        long result = 1;
        for(int i = num; i > 0; i--)
            result *= i;
        this.o = num;
        this.r = result;
    }
}
```

Should I keep the `package _Mathematics.Problems.bin;`, or should I change it to `package _Mathematics.Problems.src;`?

What is wrong with my code??

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `bin` is not a package here (or at least, it shouldn't be).  So it shouldn't appear in the package name (in your imports).  You should make sure that the bin directories appear in the classpath argument passed to `javac`.

Comment: Exception in thread “main” simply indicate that its “main” thread which is not able to find a particular class it could be any thread so just don’t worry and try to make sure the path you have given while compilation is right.

Comment: Using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans would help you prevent this type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues worth mentioning:

`bin` directories are normally used for executable files. This is because (generally) your OS will have an environment setting that points to these directories, so when you try to run a program, it knows where to look. When you run a Java program, Java itself is the executable (your OS needs to know where to find it). The OS doesn't need to find your actual Java class files, *Java* needs to find them, for which it uses a completely different environment setting (the classpath). Because of this, if you're putting Java class files in a bin directory, you're probably doing something wrong.

Secondly, your package structure (`_Mathematics.Problems.bin`) should match exactly the directory structure, but it should reflect the purpose of the classes, so `_Mathematics` and `Problems` are reasonable parts of a package structure, but, again, `bin` or `src`, is not. Normally, I would create `classes` and `src` directories and then my package structure begins under there

So, as explained above, to fix the issue:

1. make sure the directory and package structures are identical for
   your src and classes
2. by removing the bin part of your package structure, this will be
   easier.

Comment: thanks. that was a nice explanation. i get what @G V was trying to say now.

Answer (score 1):

For class files, you need to maintain the folder structure which your program is expecting

_Mathematics\Problems\bin\Permutations

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Check the folder structure of your java files. Your class files should be in exactly the same folder structure.